# WordPress style.css broken

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to style.css and just got a weird problem.

At Appearance > Editor, the style.css within child theme appears to be broken (see picture).

Any ideias what is that, and how to fix it?
[!style.css out of usual format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChOzS.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChOzS.jpg)
[!doubled theme's name[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhuIU.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhuIU.jpg)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you think it is broken? It is only minified I think.

Comment: It's either minified or you've got an issue related [to this](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like valid css, it's just that the css is minified. (Everything is jammed close together and onto one line, to make the size of the file smaller and so browsers can load it faster.)

Copy the style.css file contents into [this Unminify site](http://unminify.com/) and click the "Unminify" button. It will expand the css so it's a lot more human friendly. Then copy and paste that unminified code in place of the minified code and save those changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I'm gonna try the unminify site. Don't you think that is something wrong with the 'doubled theme name' (fig 2)?

Comment: Hi guys.
I've found a staging of my website, and replaced the style.css at child theme.
This was enough to get the result I wanted
Maybe it was a minified code, but probably something went wrong.
Now it ok.

Thank you all!!

Comment: @user9473846 Please mark the question as answered. Glad it worked out! :)